# Creating javascript objects using jQuery's each() method

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Im curious about what might be a larger question than I think.

I am using the following code to listen for 'keyup' on a group of text input fields. If the user stops typing for a given amount of time, I send the data to a controller using AJAX.

I decided to try my hand at OOP in javascript to accomplish this. This is because I want a new instance of the timer method for each input field. (To be absolutely clear, Im very new to OOP in javascript so this might be dreadful. Let me know.)

Here is the main class with its methods:

```
    function FieldListener(entity){
      t = this;

      t.typingTimer;                // Timer identifier
      t.doneTypingInterval = 1000;  // Time in ms. e.g.; 5000 = 5secs        
      t.entity = entity;

      entity.bind("keyup", function(){t.setTimer();});
    }

    FieldListener.prototype.setTimer = function(){
      t = this;

      // User is still typing, so clear the timer.
      clearTimeout(t.typingTimer);

      // Get the field name, e.g.; 'username'
      t.entityType = t.entity.attr("name");
      // If the value is empty, set it to a single space.
      if(!(t.val = t.entity.val())){
         t.val = ' ';
      }
      t.noticeSpan = t.entity.siblings("span");
      // Display 'waiting' notice to user.
      t.noticeSpan.html('...')

      t.typingTimer = setTimeout(function(){t.doneTyping();},t.doneTypingInterval);
    }

    FieldListener.prototype.doneTyping = function(){
       // Encode for passing to ajax route.
      t = this;

      valueType = encodeURIComponent(t.entityType);
      value = encodeURIComponent(t.val);

      $.ajax({
        url: '/check/'+valueType+'/'+value,
        type: 'GET',
        processData: false
      })
      .done(function(validationMessage){
        t.noticeSpan.html(validationMessage);
      })
      .fail(function(){
        t.noticeSpan.html("Something went wrong. Please try again.");
      });       
    }
```

So from here I'd like to be able to create an object of the FieldListener class for every input field.

I know I can do it easily if I have an id for each like so:

```
   var fieldListener = new FieldListener($("#someFieldID"));
```

But I'd like to iterate over every field with a given class name. Something close to this perhaps?:

```
   i = 0;
   $(".info-field").each(function(){
      i = new FieldListener($(this));
   });
```

But that doesn't work (and doesn't look very nice).

Any thoughts? (Im also curious about critiques/improvements to the class/methods code as well.)

edit: As per @ChrisHerring's question: The issue is that it seems to create the object but only for the last element in the each() method. So the span associated with the last input field with the class '.info-field' displays the validationMessage returned from AJAX regardless of which field I am typing in.

UPDATE:

It seems like something is wrong with the creation of new objects. For example, if, rather than iterating through the each() method, I simply follow one class initiation with another, like so:

```
   var fieldListener1 = new FieldListener($("#someFieldID"));
   var fieldListener2 = new FieldListener($("#someOtherFieldID"));
```

that fieldListener2 overwrites variables being saved when initiating fieldListener1. This means that when I type into the input field with id "#someFieldID", it behaves as if I am typing into the input field with id "#someOtherFieldID". Thoughts?

UPDATE #2 (solved for now):

It seems that I have solved the issue for now. I needed to add 'var' before 't = this;' in the FieldListener class. Any comments/critiques are still welcome of course. ;)

Comment: What error do you get? It looks as if it should at least create the object successfully.

Comment: @ChrisHerring, It seems to create the object but only for the last element in the each() method. So the span associated with the last input field with the class '.info-field' displays the validationMessage returned from AJAX regardless of which field I am typing in. (Added this to the OP)

Comment: I'd get into a habit of running something like jslint over your code. It'd didnt catch this issue but it will save you some time on some other issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The t variable is global. The function for the "keyup" event is evaluated dynamically which means it picks up the last value of t.

Change

```
  t = this;
```

to

```
  var t = this;
```

Comment: Thanks. I solved it myself (and edited the original post) but since this is indeed the answer, Ill go ahead and give you the 'check'. :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be using jquery's `.on()` to handle the binding.

```
$(body).on({

   keyup: function () { HandleKeyUpEvent($(this)); },
   keydown: function () { HandleKeyDownEvent($(this)); }

  }, ".info-field");
```

I realize this is a departure from your original coding idea (using prototypes) but it will still be OOP, if that's what you intented to do.

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up. It seems that bind() is an older jquery method.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want an array of `FieldListener` objects.

```
var myListeners = [];
i = 0;
$(".info-field").each(function(){
    myListeners[i] = new FieldListener($(this));
    i++
});
```

This'll give you a list of `FieldListeners`, where `myListeners[0]` is the listener for the first `.info-field` on the page, `myListeners[1]` is the listener for the second, etc.

---

Edit: It would appear you have solved the problem. This answer may still come in handy later on, though, so I won't delete it. =)